Multiple topologies in Spring Kafka streams
What's the easiest or best way to create multiple topologies in a Spring Boot Kafka streams application?
Is it possible to use the same default StreamBuilder bean? Or if I need to create a new StreamBuilder, I don't want to configure it from scratch and / or handle the stream lifecycle myself.
My actual use case is to consume the input topic, and create a Global KTable from that topic too, which is apparently not possible as same topic cannot be registered twice as a source in a Topology.
